# Magento2: Unable to save Catalog Config

Tags: magento2, database

Got the below error while updating the catalog configuration.

> Something went wrong while saving this configuration: SQLSTATE[42S02]:
>   Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'dbname.url_rewrite' doesn't
>   exist, query was: UPDATE `url_rewrite` SET `request_path` = ? WHERE
>   (`url_rewrite_id` = 62)

One thing I noticed is the table shown in the error doesn't have the table prefix. This is a migrated website from Magento 1.9.1.0 and we use table prefix.

Am I doing something wrong? or is this a core issue?

Update: I guess it is a bug.  I just removed the prefix for url_rewrite table alone and the save works great.  But after save it throws a similar error for SELECT.

**Steps I followed**

1. Login to admin back-end
2. Click on Stores -> Configuration
3. click on Catalog -> Catalog
4. Open Search Engine Optimization
5. Remove the .html suffix for both product and category
6. hit Save
7. I see the above error

**What I did next**

8. I login to my phpMyAdmin
9. Renamed the table by removing the `mag_` prefix for `url_rewrite` table
10. I flushed the cache in another browser and hit save in the current browser
11. Now the save works but when the page refreshed it shows the table `mag_url_rewite` doesn't exist.

It looks clearly a bug for me... Sorry if I might be wrong...

Comment: It looks like the setup didn't go correctly and you are missing some tables. Try removing app/etc/env.php (move it to another location) and install store again with new database.

Comment: @Zefiryn.  I did a fresh migration one more time and the result is same.

Comment: @Malaiselvan What tool/script do you use to migrate database? Do you also install Magento 2 with prefix?

Comment: @MaxPronko I use the Magento core data migration tool as-is.  My 1.9.1 store doesnt have any external module apart from the theme... It was very smooth and nice using the core Magento data migration tool.

Comment: @Malaiselvan do you see url_rewrite table after fresh Magento 2 installation?

Comment: @MaxPronko yes I could see the table as `mag_url_rewrite`.  Because I use `mag_` as prefix in old 1.9.1 and want to maintain the same in 2.0 too.

Comment: @Malaiselvan should i save Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog page to try to reproduce an issue? Or you change Marketing -> Url Rewrite record?

Comment: @MaxPronko Updated my question with the steps I did.  Hope this helps to find the cause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34384/discussion-between-max-pronko-and-malaiselvan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for `exception.log` data. You are right that `url_rewrite` table usage is hard-coded in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite\Suffix` class. So when Search Engine Optimization configuration it triggers the class `updateSuffixForUrlRewrites()` method where the constant isn't wrapped with the getTableName() method call:

```
        $this->connection->update(
            DbStorage::TABLE_NAME,
            $bind,
            $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(UrlRewrite::URL_REWRITE_ID) . ' = ' . $urlRewrite->getUrlRewriteId()
        );
```

There are 2 options on how to fix this issue:

1. Plugin for the `Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite\Suffix:: updateSuffixForUrlRewrites()` method. For this we have to inject all dependencies which Suffix has in it's contructor.
2. Update `backend_model` node for the `CatalogUrlRewrite\etc\adminhtml\system.xml` fields with id `category_url_suffix` and `product_url_suffix` in your system.xml file:

[image]

This option still requires you to fix it in your custom class.

3. Pull request into Magento 2 repository with the fix. You might wait a while until it will be available in stable release.

My recommendation is to go with 1 or 2.

Comment: Thanks for your effort to find the cause of the issue and possible options.  As a temporary solution I plan to remove the table prefix in Magento2.0 while do the migration from 1.9.1.  Once Megento team fix the issue, I will find a way to put the table prefix back.

Answer (score 2):

Here a ***quick / temporary*** fix in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/System/Config/Backend/Catalog/Url/Rewrite/Suffix.php

1 - Add appResource in the constructor

```
{
    parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    $this->urlRewriteHelper = $urlRewriteHelper;
    $this->connection = $appResource->getConnection();
    $this->appResource = $appResource;  // ###### Here ######
    $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

2 - Replace the name of the table in updateSuffixForUrlRewrites()

```
$this->connection->update(
    $this->appResource->getTableName(DbStorage::TABLE_NAME),    // ###### Here ######
    $bind,
    $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(UrlRewrite::URL_REWRITE_ID) . ' = ' . $urlRewrite->getUrlRewriteId()
);
```

Full file :

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * Url rewrite suffix backend
 */
namespace Magento\Catalog\Model\System\Config\Backend\Catalog\Url\Rewrite;

use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlPathGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlPathGenerator;
use Magento\CatalogUrlRewrite\Model\ProductUrlRewriteGenerator;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\Storage\DbStorage;
use Magento\UrlRewrite\Service\V1\Data\UrlRewrite;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Suffix extends \Magento\Framework\App\Config\Value
{
    /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite */
    protected $urlRewriteHelper;

    /** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface */
    protected $storeManager;

    /** @var \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface */
    protected $urlFinder;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface */
    protected $connection;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList
     * @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite $urlRewriteHelper
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param ResourceConnection $appResource
     * @param \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource|null $resource
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb|null $resourceCollection
     * @param array $data
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveParameterList)
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $config,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Cache\TypeListInterface $cacheTypeList,
        \Magento\UrlRewrite\Helper\UrlRewrite $urlRewriteHelper,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $appResource,
        \Magento\UrlRewrite\Model\UrlFinderInterface $urlFinder,
        \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $config, $cacheTypeList, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
        $this->urlRewriteHelper = $urlRewriteHelper;
        $this->connection = $appResource->getConnection();
        $this->appResource = $appResource;                                                          // Updated here #####################################################
        $this->urlFinder = $urlFinder;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    }

    /**
     * Check url rewrite suffix - whether we can support it
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave()
    {
        $this->urlRewriteHelper->validateSuffix($this->getValue());
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    public function afterSave()
    {
        if ($this->isValueChanged()) {
            $this->updateSuffixForUrlRewrites();
        }
        return parent::afterSave();
    }

    /**
     * Update suffix for url rewrites
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function updateSuffixForUrlRewrites()
    {
        $map = [
            ProductUrlPathGenerator::XML_PATH_PRODUCT_URL_SUFFIX => ProductUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
            CategoryUrlPathGenerator::XML_PATH_CATEGORY_URL_SUFFIX => CategoryUrlRewriteGenerator::ENTITY_TYPE,
        ];
        if (!isset($map[$this->getPath()])) {
            return $this;
        }
        $dataFilter = [UrlRewrite::ENTITY_TYPE => $map[$this->getPath()]];
        $storesIds = $this->getStoreIds();
        if ($storesIds) {
            $dataFilter[UrlRewrite::STORE_ID] = $storesIds;
        }
        $entities = $this->urlFinder->findAllByData($dataFilter);
        $oldSuffixPattern = '~' . preg_quote($this->getOldValue()) . '$~';
        $suffix = $this->getValue();
        foreach ($entities as $urlRewrite) {
            $bind = $urlRewrite->getIsAutogenerated()
                ? [UrlRewrite::REQUEST_PATH => preg_replace($oldSuffixPattern, $suffix, $urlRewrite->getRequestPath())]
                : [UrlRewrite::TARGET_PATH => preg_replace($oldSuffixPattern, $suffix, $urlRewrite->getTargetPath())];
            $this->connection->update(
                $this->appResource->getTableName(DbStorage::TABLE_NAME),                            // Updated here #####################################################
                $bind,
                $this->connection->quoteIdentifier(UrlRewrite::URL_REWRITE_ID) . ' = ' . $urlRewrite->getUrlRewriteId()
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array|null
     */
    protected function getStoreIds()
    {
        if ($this->getScope() == 'stores') {
            $storeIds = [$this->getScopeId()];
        } elseif ($this->getScope() == 'websites') {
            $website = $this->storeManager->getWebsite($this->getScopeId());
            $storeIds = array_keys($website->getStoreIds());
            $storeIds = array_diff($storeIds, $this->getOverrideStoreIds($storeIds));
        } else {
            $storeIds = array_keys($this->storeManager->getStores());
            $storeIds = array_diff($storeIds, $this->getOverrideStoreIds($storeIds));
        }
        return $storeIds;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $storeIds
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getOverrideStoreIds($storeIds)
    {
        $excludeIds = [];
        foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
            $suffix = $this->_config->getValue($this->getPath(), ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
            if ($suffix != $this->getOldValue()) {
                $excludeIds[] = $storeId;
            }
        }
        return $excludeIds;
    }
}
```

Note : I am a total noob in Magento2, this is a quick fix, and obviously not the PROPER WAY to nail it. I posted this in order to help people who will be in my current position..